# Can we measure magnitude square of angular momentum?

Tags: operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

In quantum mechanics, for spin s particles, we can write the basis state for the Hilbert space using vectors $|s,m\rangle$ where $|s,m\rangle$ stands for vectors such that

$$ \text{S}_z|s,m\rangle = m\frac{h}{2\pi}|s,m\rangle $$ and $$ \text{S}^2|s,m\rangle = s(s+1)\left(\frac{h}{2\pi}\right)^2|s,m\rangle.$$

Now, I understand that this relation can be verified experimentally for the $\text{S}_z$ using the Stern-Gerlach experiment, in the sense if you know about states you can check that some particles go up more and some go lower more depending on m and this gives you clear picture that particles emerging from the oven have different states with different m values. Now, to put it mathematically you write it using the first relation because you measured $\text{S}_z$.  But we cannot measure the squared S value in any experiment because then you know the each component squared value in just an experiment and we cant measure x y and z components at the same time. Yes, it is not the component itself but its square but is it a problem really? How do we know the second line is true experimentally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... it kinda depends on lots of details but typically for what you have in mind one does *not* measure $S^2$ directly.

There are some systems for which $L^2$ is directly accessible.  Molecules and nuclei have rotational spectral, and the energy of states is proportional to $L^2$ (the rotational energy of a top is also proportional to $\vec L\cdot \vec L$).  Thus, in [nuclear rotational bands](https://nukephysik101.wordpress.com/2019/01/18/rotational-band/), the energy difference in deformed nuclei often goes like
$$
\sim L'(L'+1)-L(L+1)=2(L+1)
$$
and this is an indirect way of measuring $L^2$.  The same principle holds in the [rotational spectroscopy of molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy#Structure_of_rotational_spectra).

The details actually depend on the type of molecule or the type of nuclear deformation.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to directly measure the square of any physical quantity. Measuring twice the same quantitity doesn't mean you have measured the square.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).